# Copy/Paste в Excel игнорируя скрытые ячейки

Tags: excel, office

В общем, есть Excel. Я делаю фильтрацию и хочу сделать вставку данных через CopyPaste из другого источника.

Например, N-ое кол-во строк.

Когда я выделяю место куда хочу вставить данные, то часть данных проваливается в скрытые ячейки.

Можно ли этого избежать?

Сценарий:

Дан такой лист

F1    F2

2

1

1

2

3

Делаем фильтр по F1=2. Скрыли часть полей. Делаем CopyPaste 2 строк в поле F2 и получаем в результате то, что одно значение ушло в скрытое поле.

Comment: Только макросом. В скрытых данные есть? должны сохраниться? Пример нужен

Comment: Скрытые вообще должны игнорироваться, как будто их нет. Пример позже добавлю.

Comment: Игнорировать не получится, если там есть данные. Логика макроса: массив данных копированных, массив ячеек для вставки. Создается новый массив: если строка видима, заполняется строкой копированной, если скрыта - данными из скрытой строки. Можно, конечно, без создания массива - заполнять строки по-отдельности, но  это медленный вариант.

Comment: Добавил сценарий.

Comment: Вы описали первый раз так (так посторонний понимает): копируем, вставляем в диапазон со скрытыми строками, часть данных получается скрыта. После дополнения: копируете при скрытых строках. Как правильно?

Comment: @vikttur 2 строки- это из какого-то другого диапазона. Они находятся вне скрытой области.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76993/discussion-between-vikttur-and-iluxa1810).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Нашел решение](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-paste-in-a-filtered-column-skipping-the-hidden-cells-in-MS-Excel):

1. Выделить столбец
2. Нажать Ctrl+G
3. Выбрать только видимые ячейки
4. Вставить

Comment: Да уж... Вопрос звучал совсем о другом... или не так понял.